# Bottom alignment on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, positioning

this is my first post here.

I'm having troubles with HTML and CSS, because I'm trying to make a 3 div simple website focused on mobile devices. For PCs I made other webpage.

In portrait mode, seems to works well on Android devices, I've tried in two devices only. For iPhone and iPad a bottom cut occurs and the page didn't fit well, the user needs to scroll down to see the bottom. I need that the page well fit on screen.

The problems get bigger when we change the device from portrait to landscape mode... The page simply doesn't fit well in any device: the bottom bar stay out of the screen and when you scroll down the bar scrolls together and overlap the content. I already tried to use percentage but doesnt work well because images will be insert.

Here is the CSS code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
 body {
   background-color: #2419B2;
 }
 #superheader {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width:100%;
height:45px;
background-color:#9991FF;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-variant:small-caps;
color: #FFF;
 }
 #supercontent {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:45px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow: auto;
 }
 #superfooter {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:30px;
background-color: #0F0A4A;
 }
```

And here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<title>3 divs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylemobilepure.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="superheader">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

</div>

<div id="supercontent">
consectetur adipiscing elit.

</div>

<div id="superfooter">
 Vestibulum iaculis lectus eu porttitor fringilla

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

The best way (I've found) to fit the page to the screen is to use

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

and just to give everything (or a wrapper) `width: 100%`.

Try absolutely positioning each div and giving each `width: 100%`.

This should work:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #2419B2;
}

div {
    width: 100%;
}

#superheader {
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #9991FF;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    color: #FFF;
}

#supercontent {
    height: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
}

#superfooter {
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #0F0A4A;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hellow jczimm, thanks for your answer. So... Your code fits very very well on Android but on iPhone and iPad doesn't fit well only in landscape mode =/